# Install xDebug with PECL on High Sierra

Tags: php, xdebug

I just updated my mac from Sierra to High Sierra. I installed PECL following those [instructions](https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-pear-pecl-mac-os-x/) and I'd like to install `xdebug` running `pecl install xdebug`.

### Output

> 79 source files, building running: phpize grep:
>
> /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory grep
>   /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory grep:
>   /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
>   Configuring for: PHP Api Version: Zend Module Api No: Zend Extension
>   Api No: building in
>   /private/tmp/pear/install/pear-build-rootPkeU2l/xdebug-2.6.0 running:
>   /private/tmp/pear/install/xdebug/configure
>   --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config /private/tmp/pear/install/xdebug/xdebug.c:25:10: fatal error: 'php.h'
>   file not found
>
> include "php.h"
>
> 1 error generated. make: *** [xdebug.lo] Error 1 ERROR: `make' failed

### Question

I feel I might did something wrong during the installation of PECL ...
What should I do ?

### FIY

```
php -v
```

> PHP 7.1.16 (cli) (built: Mar 31 2018 02:59:59) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018
>   Zend Technologies

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Need to run this

```
 xcode-select --install
```

Comment: what in OP's question would make you say that ?